# from php to c#: dictionary array, or dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, php, dictionary

I'm a newbie at programming. I have this php code, it's basically used for translating some sentences from txt files:

```
$LANG = array();

$LANG['en'] = array(
    11 => "Name",
    20 => "Surname",
    21 => "Age",
    22 => "Profession",
);
$LANG['es'] = array(
    11 => "Nombre",
    20 => "Apellido",
    21 => "Edad",
    22 => "Profesión",
);
```

I'm trying to do the same in c#, something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string>[] LANG = new Dictionary<int, string>[]
        {
        new Dictionary<int, string>(),
        LANG['en']=new Dictionary<int, string>()
             {
                 {11, "Name"},
                 {20, "Surname"},
                 {21, "Age"},
                 {22, "Profession"}
             },
        LANG['es']=new Dictionary<int, string>()
             {
                 {11, "Nombre"},
                 {20, "Apellido"},
                 {21, "Edad"},
                 {22, "Profesión"}
             }
        };
```

1) Is this c# doing exactly the same as the php code? Should i do an array of dictionaries, or should i do a dictionary of dictionaries?

2) For `LANG['en']` and `LANG['es']`, i'm getting the error message "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property 'Form1.LANG'. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. `PHP` associative array equivalent in `C#` would be a `Dictionary`. Array in `C#` doesn't support non-integer indexes so you need to use `Dictionary` with `string` key and therefore you'll have to use dictionary of dictionaries.
2. Apparently the syntax is invalid. To turn your `PHP` code into `C#` do the following

```cs
    //instantiate dictionary of dictionaries
    var LANG = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();

    //set dictionary for "en" key
    LANG["en"] = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 11, "Name" },
        { 20, "Surname" },
        { 21, "Age" },
        { 22, "Profession" }
    };

    //set dictionary for "es" key
    LANG["es"] = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 11, "Nombre" },
        { 20, "Apellido" },
        { 21, "Edad" },
        { 22, "Profesión" }
    };
```

The above can also be initialized as a single statement:

```cs
var LANG = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>
{
    { "en", new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 11, "Name" },
            { 20, "Surname" },
            { 21, "Age" },
            { 22, "Profession" }
        }
    },
    { "es", new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 11, "Nombre" },
            { 20, "Apellido" },
            { 21, "Edad" },
            { 22, "Profesión" }
        }
    }
};
```

C# now also offers an indexer-based syntax for initializing a dictionary. The equivalent of the above in the new syntax looks like this:

```cs
var LANG = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>
{
    ["en"] = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        [11] = "Name",
        [20] = "Surname",
        [21] = "Age",
        [22] = "Profession"
    },

    ["es"] = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        [11] = "Nombre",
        [20] = "Apellido",
        [21] = "Edad",
        [22] = "Profesión"
    }
};
```